# Return values after verifying an account balance on private network

Tags: erc-20, balances

When i verify the balance of an account after deploing an ERC20 token, i receive this returns:

```
  BN { negative: 0, words: [ 50, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }
```

I know that "50" is the number of token. May someone explain me what do the other things mean please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BN stands for Big number.

you can have the meaning of all these fields in the the [BN.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/) library documentation as this later is used by web3js (1.0.) to deal with big numbers.

EXP :

1. negative for bit sign
2. red for reduction